# How to async load Material ui fonts?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

I use Material-UI and its fonts block render of the first page. By default, if I don't load any fonts, materialui use Helvetica font. And the main idea is to use it until Roboto will be downloaded.

```
/signup (localhost)
    …media/roboto-latin-500.4b218fc7.woff2 (localhost) - 763,7ms, 14,5KB
    …media/roboto-latin-400.a2647ffe.woff2 (localhost) - 769,5ms, 14,5KB
```

How to async import fonts instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
```

or

```
import 'typeface-roboto'
```

I tried to implement a method with 'media' attribute and @font-face observer

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" media="bogus"/>
```

but it doesn't work. Also I used a plugin font loader from fontfaceobserver.com

I use version 1.0.0-beta.3 of Material-UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webfontloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader) library can be used to postpone the start of your application until fonts have downloaded.  This is beneficial because it allows you to [avoid FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text)](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-avoid-fout-by-adding-a-web-font-preloader--webdesign-8287), which is caused by rendering a page with the default fonts while the intended web font is downloaded

Here is an example of using webfontloader to postpone the start of your application:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

// callback that mounts the application
const app = () => {
    render(
        <div>Instead of this div, render your initial component/routes here</div>,
        document.querySelector('#main'),
    );
};

// postpone initiation of app until fonts are active
const webFontConfig = {
    google: {
        families: ['Roboto'],
    },
    custom: {
        families: ['FontAwesome'],
        urls: [
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
            'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
            'https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css',
        ],
    },
    classes: false,
    timeout: 1000,
    active: app, // invoked when fonts are active
};

// application entry point
WebFont.load(webFontConfig);
```

In the web font config, the active attribute is set to a function that will be invoked when the fonts have been downloaded and are ready to use.  Note, this may seem slow on the initial use of your application, but with the benefit of caching, subsequent visits should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to get a first meaningful paint faster. It's opposite what you suggest. And if you have read the text carefully you should understand that rendering a page with the default fonts while the intended web font is downloaded is exactly what I need. But I'll try in any way.

Comment: That is fine, but be ready for flicker or other issues that arise with components that perform measurements when rendering.  They will measure with the default fonts, Roboto will finish loading, and the measurements will be incorrect due to differences in font size (see: Selected Tab's ink bar).

Comment: if I import webfontloader  in HTML with an async attribute it works

Answer (score 0):

For loading a `<link/>` async the proper way (without too much hacking), I recommend to read this: https://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript

It provides a non-blocking `link` loading solution as simple as (of course, `if IE` conditionals exist because the browsers may not work the same):

```
<head>
  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" lazyload>
  <!-- <![endif]-->
</body>
```